# "Undistract-me" doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04.4 to Ubuntu 18.04.1. One of the most important tools to me is "undistract-me", it show notifications when terminal commands are done. It's in the default repos (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/undistract-me). It used to work in Ubuntu 14.04 , but now when I install it , it simply doesn't do anything. How can I make it work once again?

Answer (score 2):

As undistract-me doesn't work anymore.... I've found an alternative ; It's called NTFY,FOSS , built with Python and does exactly what undistract-me did . It's really easy to use and install, just install `sudo apt install python-pip` ,`sudo pip install ntfy` follow the instructions in https://ntfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/